# How to handle transferring ERC20 tokens (such as USDT) with delegation to pay the gas fees on behalf of users?

Tags: transactions, ether, erc-20, gas, ethgasstation

I am working on creating wallets and generating addresses to be provided to a number of users. I am wondering how can I enable them to transfer their **ERC20 tokens(such as USDT**) without having any Eth in their addresses and pay the associated gas fees through a **single delegated account on their behalf**.

I have read through Gas Station Network (GSN) docs, and so far my understanding is that we have to write a smart a contract with enabling a feature like this on that particular contract to have this ability. However, I'd like to now how can I interact with the current existing contracts on the network to perform the above explained transactions.

Answer (score 0):

> without having any ETH

Impossible; an account must own ETH in order to execute a transaction. The only thing that you can do is to transfer tokens (or ETH) back to the sender account at the end of the transaction, in order to compensate it for the initial payment.